# Is it risky to disable +MultiViews

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, virtualhost

I have a (famous) little bug, when my page is called like this :
URL/index.php/ (With a trailing slash)

It blows up everything.
I saw that disabling +MultiViews in .htacces or virtualhost could resolve this problem.

Do you know if disabling this could have negative side effects ?
What's the best practice ?

I also have another option activated : +FollowSymLinks.

I checked Apache2 documentation and I'm not sure if I should also disable this or not.
My server is used for a classic web hosting, so what's the point of symlinks here ?

Thanks for your explanations

Comment: Most of the time Multiviews can be disabled with no issue. What is does is try to do a filematch search. So you can enter something like example.com/join and it will search for file names starting with join and. If it finds it, it servers it. Most don't care for this feature as it can cause issues the pretty urls and other things. [Read here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) It can be safely turned off. It's disabled on all my setups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not risky at all. Go ahead.

MultiViews is a wacky Apache feature which will allow a single URL to serve up multiple resources depending on various parameters of the request. (For instance, it could serve an HTML document in multiple languages depending on the user's language settings, or serve multiple formats for an image file depending on which ones the user's browser supported.)

For most use cases, there is no reason whatsoever to have MultiViews enabled. Unless you are specifically using it, you should disable it.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. What about FollowSymLink ? Do you think it's safe to disable it ? I saw it could impact URL rewriting but I don't see why

Comment: Nevermind, mod_rewrite requires FollowSymLink. No further explanation needed :)